# Upload image to a canvas and add extra elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop, image-uploading

Good evening,

So, I have been working on a project, where I have to upload an image form the pc to a canvas and when the image is there I have to add elements over the image that are available over the canvas.

What i got so far is the dragable elements to canvas ([example](http://www.drconstrucciones.net/demo/draganddrop/draganddrop3.html)), and here is the code code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    contador = 0; 
    function start(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.effecAllowed = 'copyMove'; 
        e.dataTransfer.setData("Data", e.target.id); 
        e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target, 10, 10); 
        e.target.style.opacity = '0.4'; 
    }

    function end(e){
        e.target.style.opacity = '';            
        e.dataTransfer.clearData("Data");
    }

    function enter(e) {
        e.target.style.border = '3px dotted #555'; 
    }

    function leave(e) {
        e.target.style.border = ''; 
    }

    function over(e) {
        var elemArrastrable = e.dataTransfer.getData("Data"); 
        var id = e.target.id; 


        if (id == 'cuadro1'){
            return false; 
        }

        if (id == 'cuadro2'){
            return false; 
        }   



        if (id == 'papelera')
            return false; 

    }




    function drop(e){

        var elementoArrastrado = e.dataTransfer.getData("Data"); 
        e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado));
        e.target.style.border = ''; 
        tamContX = $('#'+e.target.id).width();
        tamContY = $('#'+e.target.id).height();

        tamElemX = $('#'+elementoArrastrado).width();
        tamElemY = $('#'+elementoArrastrado).height();

        posXCont = $('#'+e.target.id).position().left;
        posYCont = $('#'+e.target.id).position().top;

        x = e.layerX;
        y = e.layerY;

        if (posXCont + tamContX <= x + tamElemX){
            x = posXCont + tamContX - tamElemX;
        }

        if (posYCont + tamContY <= y + tamElemY){
            y = posYCont + tamContY - tamElemY;
        }

        document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado).style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado).style.left = x + "px";
        document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado).style.top = y + "px";
    }

    function eliminar(e){
        var elementoArrastrado = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData("Data")); 
        elementoArrastrado.parentNode.removeChild(elementoArrastrado); 
        e.target.style.border = '';   
    }


    function clonar(e){
        var elementoArrastrado = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData("Data")); 

        elementoArrastrado.style.opacity = ''; 

        var elementoClonado = elementoArrastrado.cloneNode(true); 
        elementoClonado.id = "ElemClonado" + contador; 
        contador += 1;  
        elementoClonado.style.position = "static";  
        e.target.appendChild(elementoClonado); 
        e.target.style.border = '';   
    }


</script>
```

Now, i have seen great examples here for uploading images to canvas (http://jsfiddle.net/influenztial/qy7h5/), but how can i combine the image upload into canvas and then the scripting of adding elements to this same image?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you ask/try to achieve. And the example link is broken.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, the link had a wrong symbol. Now if you click on the link, it will work. Also, i achieved what I wanted with div overlay, but my code its really messy to be honest. Please check out the sorce code.